# Connecting front end pages angularjs to the sql database java servlets code

Tags: eclipse, angular, visual-studio, rest

I am a beginner to Angularjs so I have developed front end pages using Visual Studio Code.For example I have developed a registration front page in the visual studio code and I would like to insert the inputs into the backend into the oracle sql database. Please help!